# PHP : Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, soap

I want to return a value from the below scripts :

```
$wsdl_url = 'http://srv.test/erProject/services/services?wsdl';
    $client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);
    $params = array(
        'IPADDR' => "111.12.13.14",
    );
    $return = $client->getUserInfo($params);
    print_r($return);
    echo $return->getUserInfo->expiredate;
```

print_r work and return:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [UserCredit] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [expiredate] => 23-02-2018
                )

            [resCode] => 1
        )

)
```

but echo will return :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$UserCredit
>
> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `print_r()` shows the expected structure.  `$return->return->UserCredit->expiredate`.  The property of the object stored in `$return` is `return`.

Comment: We don't now how `getUserInfo($params)` works, you can use this `echo $return->return->UserCredit->expiredate;`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to echo a stdClass, you should use something like this:

```
echo $return->return->UserCredit->expiredate;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a notice and it tells you that `$client` class has no property `$UserCredit` (type object).